# linux prompt: show current branch?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I want to have my command prompt to not display my username, but to show what git branch I am currently in. In other words, this is what I want:

```
[master]$ ls
README    INSTAL    whatever.py
[master]$ git checkout other-branch
[other-branch]$
```

Is there a way to have the prompt customized that much?

Answer (score 2):

```
PS1='[`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null`]$ '
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417957/show-just-the-current-branch-in-git) for help on the particular git command used. The key for me was to realize that I can plug arbitrary commands into the PS1 environment variable :)